# Return values from components in ngFor loop

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have the following html in my main component:

```
<app-loc-list-item *ngFor="let loc of locs; let i = index" [loc]="loc" [i]="i"></app-loc-list-item>
```

The `LocListItemComponent` looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

....

export class LocListItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() loc: Location;
  @Input('i') index: number;
  selected: boolean = false;

  onLocationSelect() {
    this.selected = !this.selected;
  }
}
```

Now, there can be any number of those little components and between `0` and `n` can have the value `selected = true`. I now want to receive the `index` values for each of those components that have `selected = true`.

How can I access those index values?

Comment: Are you changing the selected from LocListItemComponent ?

Comment: Good point, I do indeed, edited in the function to do so. It's a simple click listener.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you only want to query the 'app-loc-list-item' children from the parent component then include this line of code in the parent

```
@ViewChildren(LocListItem) listItems: QueryList<LocListItem>
```

so you can iterate over the listItems property in your parent and see which ones have been selected

Comment: This sounds interesting. I will give it a try and see if that is all I need to implement.

Comment: This is a great answer. I like how simple it is. One thing to add is that I need to import the component as well.

Answer (score 4):

For that you can use

> `@Output` : used to pass data from child component to parent component

**Parent Component :**

```
<app-loc-list-item *ngFor="let loc of locs; let i = index" [loc]="loc" [i]="i" (change)="selectChange($event)"></app-loc-list-item>

selectChange(data)
{
    console.log(data);
}
```

**Child Component :**

```
export class LocListItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() loc: Location;
  @Input('i') index: number;
  @Output()change: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  selected: boolean = false;

  onLocationSelect() {
    this.selected = !this.selected;
    let data = { 'index' : this.index , 'selected' : this.selected }
    this.change.emit(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer works as well, so I upvoted it but Dean's answer is way shorter and requires less code especially on the children. Thanks for your help though and I did test yours and works like a charm as well.

Comment: @Spurious, no problem , glad that you found 2 solutions and me too. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no double data-binding between component in Angular (that was in AngularJs).

There is some ways for your problem, one way is:

- to use a service where you define locs and in your child component

you have:

```
this.yourServices.locs.splice(index, 1)
```

**Edit: What I said is not right. This will be the case between component not  correlated.**

Comment: I feel like a `service` is an overkill. I don't want to create a `service` just for a single purpose array.